# Recommendation for Reseller Web Hosting - With Linux/Apache & IIS Options

Tags: linux, windows, web-hosting, reseller

I work for an IT consulting company, and many of our clients have been asking about switching their website hosting to us so that they only have to deal with one outfit.

We have done some small scale hosting off of our own servers before, but we'd like to go with an actual webhost for reliability and consistency.

Our main issue is that our clients have a wide mix of websites - some just static html, some that are using PHP/MySQL, some ASP/.NET/MSSQL, etc. What we'd like to find is a web hosting reseller that provides a single plan with access to IIS and Apache, so that we don't have to worry about rewriting any backend code for our client's websites when we take over the hosting for them.

One example I found is [LooseFoot](http://www.lfchosting.com/hosting.shtml), but I'm wondering if anyone else has experience with similar providers that they can recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reseller plans at [Jodohost](http://www.jodohost.com) are ok, the plan includes both linux/windows hosting; you can opt for either on a per site basis (it's pretty flexible). They seem to be a pretty large scale outfit, and their support was always good / speedy.

The downside is though, at the end of the day, it's still shared/budget hosting (unless you opt for a server but of course you then lose the OS options unless you get 2), but if you can live with that, they aren't too bad. Just putting it out there really :)

Answer (score 1):

My friends speak very well of [hetzner](http://hetzner.de/en/) housing. It's cheap, very qualitative and you have the freedom to do whatever you want.